# Efficient way to buffering characters and searchig for pattern c#

Tags: c#, string, char, buffer

I'm doing an algorythm to receive data from serial port and I'm searching the best and efficient way to do that.

I need to store received characters and searh for pattern `\r\nETX?` ETX could be optional. If I identify the pattern I have to get all characters that I have received before that.

I'm thinking in use a stack or Queue and a variable to store latest received characters. But if that variable is a string maybe is not the best because of the string inmutability. Maybe something like StringBuilder with fixed length and automatically removing old characters to append new ones. I don't know if there is some structure whitch has this behaviour.

The other point is that regex evaluation or comparision like StartsWith or EndsWith works only with strings and not with other structures.

If I'm not mistaken building and doing string modifications too much times is not so efficient because of inmutability, but using StringBuilder has the difficult of doing modifications and comparitions.

Currently I have this approach.

```
private static readonly SerialMessageProcessPatternDto _endMessagePattern = new SerialMessageProcessPatternDto(
    patternRegex: $"{AsciiConstants.Cr}{AsciiConstants.Lf}{AsciiConstants.Etx}?",
    minLength: 2, maxLength: 3);

protected override async Task ReadingTask(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    int verifyCheckStartIndex;
    int checkStartIndex;
    int lengthToCheck;
    int lastIndexCheck = 0;
    string currentStringCheck;
    MatchCollection currentMatches;
    StringBuilder messageBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    
    while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var readedBuffer = await _serialComm.ReadAsync(cancelToken);
        if (!readedBuffer.IsEmpty())
        {
            var readedStr = _messageEncoding.GetString(readedBuffer, 0, readedBuffer.Length);
            messageBuffer.Append(readedStr);
            if(messageBuffer.Length > _endMessagePattern.MinLength)
            {
                verifyCheckStartIndex = _endMessagePattern.MinLength - (messageBuffer.Length - lastIndexCheck);
                checkStartIndex = verifyCheckStartIndex < 0 ? lastIndexCheck : lastIndexCheck - (verifyCheckStartIndex * -1);
                lengthToCheck = messageBuffer.Length - checkStartIndex;
                currentStringCheck = messageBuffer.ToString(checkStartIndex, lengthToCheck);
                currentMatches = _endMessagePattern.PatternRegex.Matches(currentStringCheck);
                for(var idx = 0; idx < currentMatches.Count; idx++)
                {
                    var match = currentMatches[idx];
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        var messageLength = lastIndexCheck + match.Index + match.Length;
                        var message = messageBuffer.ToString(0, messageLength);
                        messageBuffer.Remove(0, messageLength);
                        lastIndexCheck = lastIndexCheck - messageLength;
                        OnMessageReadedFromSerialPort(message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whitch could be the best way to do this or the best data structures to use in cases like this.

Comment: Just store the bytes? And only if you receive the mentioned pattern then Encode it as string?

Comment: Also i don't understand what you are trying to do with Regex. \r\nETX are 2 or 3 explicitly defined well known bytes.

Comment: Yes, it could be possible to store bytes and convert them to string when pattern is found. I thougth on regex because It is a good option to express patterns where some part is optional like ETX in this case.

Comment: I don't understand the optional part here. Does it mean you want to wait after a Newline for a minute or so if an ETX follows and if do you do something different?

Comment: The optional is ETX character. The message could end with \r\n or with \r\nETX. That's why I suggested to use regex because it's a good way to express patterns like that ...

Comment: @Ralf I have added my currently approach.